# How to avoid using the name of a custom collection class when serialized

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

I have a custom collection class as a property of another class like this:

```
class MyDataClass
{
    CustomCollection<MyType> DataCollection;
}
```

It implements IXmlSerializable, so it can be serialized just fine.  My only complaint is that the resulting xml looks like this:

```
<MyDataClass>
  <DataCollection>
    <MyType />
    <MyType />
  </DataCollection>
</MyDataClass>
```

When I don't want the collection to be in xml, just like this:

```
<MyDataClass>
  <MyType />
  <MyType />
</MyDataClass>
```

I've read that for Lists and Arrays, you can add the [XmlElement] attribute to tell the xml serializer to render the collection as an unwrapped list of elements, but that's not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
public class MyDataClass
{
    [XmlElement("MyType")]
    public CustomCollection<MyType> DataCollection;

} 

public class CustomCollection<T> : List<T> { }
public class MyType { }

public static void Main()
{
    MyDataClass c = new MyDataClass();
    c.DataCollection = new CustomCollection<MyType>();
    c.DataCollection.Add(new MyType { });
    c.DataCollection.Add(new MyType { });

    XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyDataClass));
    StringWriter sww = new StringWriter();
    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww);
    xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, c);
    var xml = sww.ToString(); // Your xml
}
```

And the resulting xml looks like

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
    <MyDataClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <MyType /> 
      <MyType /> 
   </MyDataClass>
```

Comment: Not working for me, but I notice that my custom collection inherits from Dictionary<int, T>.  Could this be why it's not working?

Comment: Yes, you can't serialize a class that implements IDictionary, check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx) " The XmlSerializer cannot process classes implementing the IDictionary interface. This was partly due to schedule constraints and partly due to the fact that a hashtable does not have a counterpart in the XSD type system. The only solution is to implement a custom hashtable that does not implement the IDictionary interface."